# BBB [debian] - bring up can 0 at startup

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I have a beaglebone black running lastet official debian.
I've added a custom cape to /etc/default/capemgr:

```
CAPE=BB-DCAN1
```

I also added these lines to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto can0
iface can0 can static
    bitrate 1000000
```

and executing *ifup -a* after booting works just fine. 
Can anyone explain how to bring can0 up at startup?

Comment: have you tried appending the line `ifup -a` in the .bashrc file? its full path should be `~/.bashrc`. Commands in the .bashrc file are executed at startup.

Comment: I will try. I executed "ifup -a" from own script in /etc/init.d/canup, output was: unable to bring up can0.

Comment: yup, I will put that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to execute a command at startup, you can simply append the command in the `.bashrc` file. In your case, you can simply append `ifup -a` in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto can0
iface can0 can static
   bitrate 1000000
```

I have the same thing in my interfaces file, it only differs by bitrate (500000).  If your dtsi isn't setup right, that may effect whether can0 can be provisioned at start up.  My can0 comes up automatically with no problems.